# Global detect browser and show different view in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that I want to detect what browser the user is using globally so for example if they visit: `app.com/login` or `app.com/organisations` etc the check will still happen.

What file would I be best putting such code in? The code should check if their browser is a certain version and if so then load a different view and layout.

so e.g.

```
if(browser is ie < 9)

return ('chromeFrame');

elseif (browser is ff < 4 etc)

return ('upgradeBrowser');
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

To clarify this wouldn't be a redirect rather calling different views and layout if the browser isn't correct so the url wouldn't change and it would happen on any url!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be using `HttpBrowserCapabilities` that is exposed on the `Request` as [`Request.Browser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3k2ssx2.aspx).

Be mindful however that the .browser file that is used to identify browser capabilities may not be updated as frequently as new browser versions are released.